# Bind spec file unusual syntax

Tags: bind, rpmbuild

I have been building rpms for a while now, but when I extracted bind.spec from bind-9.8.2-0.23.rc1.el6_5.1.src.rpm, I have found an unusual syntax I cannot understand:

```
%{?!SDB:       %define SDB       1}
%{?!test:      %define test      0}
%{?!bind_uid:  %define bind_uid  25}
%{?!bind_gid:  %define bind_gid  25}
%{?!GSSTSIG:   %define GSSTSIG   1}
%{?!PKCS11:    %define PKCS11    0}
```

I need to make sure that the rpm is compiled with `--with-gssapi=/usr/include/gssapi --with-dlopen=yes`.
In the %build section, the configure command has conditionals for the variables declared above, like this:

```
%if %{GSSTSIG}
  --with-gssapi=yes \
  --disable-isc-spnego \
%endif
```

My guess is that those sections do something very similar to :

```
%define PKCS11=0
```

But there must be something else I am not grasping in this syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only guess, but I think they are here to provide a conditional `%define`.

Let's try that:

```
Name:           blabla
Version:        1.3.2
Release:        0.1
License:        GPL
Summary:        my awesome lib
BuildRoot:      %{_tmppath}/%{name}-%{version}-build
%{?!TESTDEF:  %define TESTDEF undefined}

%description

%prep
echo %TESTDEF
```

If I run a pure `rpmbuild -ba empty.spec` now, I get

```
...
+ echo undefined
undefined
...
```

OTOH, if I run `rpmbuild -D 'TESTDEF 9' -ba empty.spec`, I get

```
...
+ echo 9
9
...
```

If I omit both, I get

```
...
+ echo %TESTDEF
%TESTDEF
...
```

which is probably not what I want.

So this line indeed provides a useful default for the case no one else (the one who actually runs the build, or the one who provides the build environment) sets this variable.